# Horizontal navbar scroll on smaller devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar, nav, horizontal-scrolling

I'm using bootstrap 4. I created a second navigation bar using

```
<div class="nav-active-border b-danger bottom">
    <ul class="nav nav-active-border b-warning flex-row">
       <li class="nav-item">Link 1</li>
       <li class="nav-item">Link 2</li>
       <li class="nav-item">Link 3</li>
       <li class="nav-item">Link 4</li>
       <li class="nav-item">Link 5</li>
       <li class="nav-item">Link 6</li>
       <li class="nav-item">Link 7</li>
       <li class="nav-item">Link 8</li>
       <li class="nav-item">Link 9</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This however, on mobiles shows in two rows are there are multiple items. How to create a horizontal scroll for these nav items on mobile with indicators just for mobile layouts. It shows perfect on desktops and laptops

I'm trying to achieve the same like on google
https://www.google.co.in/intl/en/about/products/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created something like this with Bootstrap 4 using the flexbox utility classes.

A little jQuery is used to toggle the `justify-content-end` class which aligns the nav items to the right side, instead of the left. You can toggle to slide the nav in either direction. CSS transition is used for sliding animation.

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/IHwAx16j14

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <a href="#" class="btn-left btn-link toggle p-2"><i class="ion-chevron-left"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-grow-1 w-100 o-hidden">
            <ul class="nav nav-fill text-uppercase position-relative flex-nowrap">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Self</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">World</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Lifestyle</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Bio</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Politics</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Local</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Science</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Tech</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Health</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Food</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Design</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Culture</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Travel</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">More</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-shrink-0">
            <a href="#" class="btn-right btn-link toggle p-2"><i class="ion-chevron-right"></i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$('.toggle').click(function(){
    $('.nav').toggleClass("justify-content-end");
});
```

CSS

```
.o-hidden {
    overflow:hidden;
}

.nav {
    transition: transform 0.4s;
    transform: translateX(50%);
    left: -50%;
}

.nav.justify-content-end {
    transform: translateX(0);
    left: 0;
}
```